# Cordova 3.1.0 Media Not loading sound

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova

I am facing an issue from Cordova library after updating to 3.1.0 .

When I want to play an audio file, I have this in my safari console :

```
Cannot use audio file from resource '../../../../Library/Caches/data/commonFolder/build/media/voice.mp3'
```

The audio file is in this folder, because when I do :

```
window.document.href='../../../../Library/Caches/data/commonFolder/build/media/voice.mp3'
```

on my ipad simulator, it does find the file and plays it.

On xcode, I have this error :

```
Unknown resource '../../../../Library/Caches/data/commonFolder/build/media/voice.mp3'
```

Is there anything wrong with this update ? Everything worked fine before ( I had this plugin though : org.apache.cordova.core.AudioHandler )

Comment: Which version did you update from? What did you do to update? If you are going from 2.x to 3.1.0, you'll have to add the media plugin to your project.

Comment: I updated from 3.0.0. I did : npm install -g cordova

Then I installed the media plugin : cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media 

and remove the old one : org.apache.cordova.core.AudioHandler 
which worked well.

It seems like to work when I play a media in /www, but I have those messages when I want to play a .mp3 under /Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been a change in cordova API I guesss because now I can access my .mp3 with this path :

```
'../Library/Caches/data/commonFolder/build/media/voice.mp3'
```

So there is just one level to go up instead of 4 before.